# Why is my event listener not working? No Javascript console errors

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the `href` of a class when a button is clicked. However, I have not been able to achieve this. There are no errors shown in the Javascript console.

```js
var clicker0 = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-button elementor-button--checkout elementor-size-md");
for (var i = 0; i < clicker0.length; i++) {
  clicker0[i].addEventListener("click", clicker1);
}

function clicker1(esc1112) {
  esc1112.preventDefault();
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('coupon') === '1') {
    clicker0[i].href = 'https://www.test.com/checkout/?coupon_code=yyyy';
  } else {
    clicker0[i].href = 'https://www.test.com/checkout/?coupon_code=xxxx';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.test.com/checkout/" class="elementor-button elementor-button--checkout elementor-size-md">
  <span class="elementor-button-text">Checkout</span>
</a>
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/L0d7yv59/

**Expected outcome**

When the button is clicked, it should redirect users to https://www.test.com/checkout/?coupon_code=xxxx since session storage is blank for the moment. However, the link still keeps directing to the original link (https://www.test.com/checkout/)

Thank you.

Comment: @CalvinNunes `getElementsByClassName` so no.... it is not querySelectorAll

Comment: that "i" in the click event would be unknown as well

Answer (score 1):

When the event listener runs, `i == clicker0.length` (assuming you haven't reused the global variable `i` for anything else). So `clicker0[i]` will be undefined.

Use `esc1112.currentTarget` to get the element that was clicked on.

```js
var clicker0 = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-button elementor-button--checkout elementor-size-md");
for (var i = 0; i < clicker0.length; i++) {
  clicker0[i].addEventListener("click", clicker1);
}

var coupon = '1'; // because sessionStorage doesn't work in Stack Snippets.

function clicker1(esc1112) {
  esc1112.preventDefault();
  if (coupon === '1') {
    esc1112.currentTarget.href = 'https://www.test.com/checkout/?coupon_code=yyyy';
  } else {
    esc1112.currentTarget.href = 'https://www.test.com/checkout/?coupon_code=xxxx';
  }
  console.log(document.querySelector(".elementor-button").href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.test.com/checkout/" class="elementor-button elementor-button--checkout elementor-size-md">
  <span class="elementor-button-text">Checkout</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

just change :

```
clicker0[i].href = "something"
```

to this in both lines :

```
clicker0[0].href ="something";
```

change i to 0 in your function

Comment: Thank you. Tried this and it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/L0d7yv59/4/